# How to change version of Goblin OGM Serializer for Janusgraph (TinkerPop 3.2.6) #101

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server, goblin

I am trying out a Python application to connect to a Janusgraph 0.2.0. I followed all the setup instructions and I am able to create elements in the graph and traverse them successfully.

```
import asyncio

from goblin import Goblin
from quart import jsonify, Quart, serving
from app.models import Person, Knows

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
goblin_app = loop.run_until_complete(Goblin.open(loop,
hosts = ['localhost'],
port = '8182',
scheme = 'ws'))
goblin_app.register(Person, Knows)
print("Initialized all the goblin stuff")
quart_app = Quart(name)

async def create(app, data):
session = await app.session()
session.add(data)
await session.flush()
return data

leif = Person()
leif.name = 'Leif'
leif.age = 28
leif = loop.run_until_complete(create(goblin_app, leif))

jon = Person()
jon.name = 'Jon'
jon.age = 32
jon = loop.run_until_complete(create(goblin_app, jon))

works_with = Knows(leif, jon)
works_with = loop.run_until_complete(goblin_app, works_with)
```

However, when I try to connect from my application and send session.flush() to create an element, the application freezes and nothing else happens.
In the gremlin-server.log I am seeing the following error:

> 1109015 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder
>   - Gremlin Server is not configured with a serializer for the requested mime type [application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json] - using
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0
>   by default 1109035 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0
>   - Request [PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 558, widx: 558, cap: 592)] could not be deserialized by
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0.
>   1109039 [gremlin-server-worker-1] WARN
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpSelectorHandler -
>   Invalid OpProcessor requested [null]
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpProcessorException: Invalid
>   OpProcessor requested [null] at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpSelectorHandler.decode(OpSelectorHandler.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpSelectorHandler.decode(OpSelectorHandler.java:50)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerProtocolHandler$1.channelRead(WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.java:159)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:312)
>   at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:286)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1302)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
>   at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460) at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~

I found some information about replacing the version the GraphSON versions in the gremlin-server.yaml file to add the missing serializer for gremlin-v3.0+json, and I did that, however when I added that I get an error about not being able to find the configured serializer class:
10348 [main] WARN org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer - Could not find configured serializer class - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 - it will not be available 1

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way that I can change the version of the serializer that my application is sending to the Gremlin Server to one of the compatible versions
2. Would it work if I download the GraphSON version 3.0 and place it in the server? This would mean that I would have to upgrade the version of Gremlin Server packaged with Janusgraph, which seems to be too much...

Has anyone run into a similar problem and has any suggestions ?

Comment: Is your Python code pulling in `gremlinpython`? If so, check and make sure it's aligned with the Apache TinkerPop version 3.2.6 that JanusGraph 0.2.0 uses.

Comment: Thank you Jason Plurad, this took care of the problem. I had a newer version of  gremlinpython installed, Once I downgraded to 3.2.6 the errors went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and make sure the `gremlinpython` version is aligned with the Apache TinkerPop version 3.2.6 that JanusGraph 0.2.0 uses.